# Errors while passing arguments into pthread_create() function - Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, pthreads

The following code is returning the error:

> error C2664: 'pthread_create' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'void
> *(__cdecl *)(void)' to 'void *(__cdecl *)(void *)'
>
> error C2664: 'pthread_create' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'void
> *(__cdecl *)(void)' to 'void *(__cdecl *)(void *)'

Code:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
int main()  {
  pthread_t f2_thread, f1_thread; 
  void *f2(), *f1();
  int i1,i2;
  i1 = 1;
  i2 = 2;
  pthread_create(&f1_thread,NULL,f1,&i1);
  pthread_create(&f2_thread,NULL,f2,&i2);
  pthread_join(f1_thread,NULL);
  pthread_join(f2_thread,NULL);
  
  return 0;

}
void *f1(int *x){
  int i;
  i = *x;
 Sleep(1);
  printf("f1: %d",i);
  pthread_exit(0); 
}
void *f2(int *x){
  int i;
  i = *x;
 Sleep(1);
  printf("f2: %d",i);
  pthread_exit(0); 
}
```

Environment:

- Visual C++ 2008 with Pthreads Win32 (http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question (or what your question was), but here is some code that compiles and gives what you might expect for the output:

```
    #include <windows.h> 
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <pthread.h> 
    int main()  {
      pthread_t f2_thread, f1_thread; 
      void *f2(void*), *f1(void*);
      int i1,i2;
      i1 = 1;
      i2 = 2;
      pthread_create(&f1_thread,NULL,f1,&i1);
      pthread_create(&f2_thread,NULL,f2,&i2);
      pthread_join(f1_thread,NULL);
      pthread_join(f2_thread,NULL);

      return 0;

    }
    void *f1(void *x){
  int* data = static_cast<int*>(x);
      int i = *data;
      Sleep(1);
      printf("f1: %d",i);
      pthread_exit(0); 
      return 0;
    }
    void *f2(void *x){
      int* data = static_cast<int*>(x);
      int i = *data;
      Sleep(1);
      printf("f2: %d",i);
      pthread_exit(0); 
      return 0;
    }
```

So

1. Having void* arguments in the prototypes then casting those to int*
2. Having each function return 0

Answer (score 0):

Please add "return NULL:" before exit your thread functions.